Can't ping IPv6 local link
I am new to IPv6 world. I feel like I should be able to do this but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have a GNS3 server deployed on Digtal Ocean running on Ubuntu. Additionally inside my GNS3, I have deployed an Ubuntu VM and connected it to the eth0 port on the cloud interface.
Here are the result when I run ip -6 add show on GNS3 server.
root@gns3vm:~# ip -6 address print
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
inet6 <redacted_for_security> scope global
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::d8b7:8dff:fec8:a310/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
inet6 fe80::d4a0:ff:fe98:692b/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun1194: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UNKNOWN qlen 100
inet6 fe80::320e:fa17:6d2a:5bfb/64 scope link stable-privacy
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Here are the results I get when running IP -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2604:a880:4:1d0::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev tun1194 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via 2604:a880:4:1d0::1 dev eth0 proto static metric 1024 pref medium

On the Ubuntu server who Eth1 is connected to Eth0 of the cloud interface, running the same command gives me
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKOWN qlen 1000
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3:<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
inet 6 fe80::e6f:c3ff:fefc:0/64 scope link
    valid_lft forever preferred_left forever

Trying to ping from any machine times out.
root@gns3vm:~# ping6 fe80::e6f:c3ff:fefc:0%eth0
PING fe80::e6f:c3ff:fefc:0%eth0(fe80::e6f:c3ff:fefc:0%eth0) 56 data bytes
11 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 10217ms

What I don't understand is why I can't ping these devices to each other?
